# What does exactly Dependency Injection in Symfony2 do?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

I registered my services.yml file like below :

```
services:
  PMI.form.users_tasks:
        class: PMI\UserBundle\Form\UsersTasksType
        arguments: 
             EntityManager: "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
```

I can list it by `php app/console container:debug`, so that mean my service is registered properly.

In my UsersTasksType class I have like below :

```
class UsersTasksType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $ur;

    public function __construct(EntityManager  $ur )
    {
        $this->setUr($ur);
    }

    // Get and setters
}
```

Does Dependency Injection mean that I don't have to pass the `EntityManager`  to the class constructor anymore? Or what ?

Because when I have to run the code below :

```
$form   = $this->createForm(new UsersTasksType(), $entity);
```

I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to PMI\UserBundle\Form\UsersTasksType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\PMI_sf2\src\PMI\UserBundle\Controller\UsersTasksController.php on line 74 and defined in C:\wamp\www\PMI_sf2\src\PMI\UserBundle\Form\UsersTasksType.php line 19
```

And I have to do something below :

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$form   = $this->createForm(new UsersTasksType($em), $entity);
```

So what would be the whole purpose of Dependency Injection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency Injection basically gives one service (in this case, your UserTasksType) access to another service (in this case, your the entity manager).

```
arguments: 
     EntityManager: "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
```

These two lines tell Symfony to expect the entity manager service to be passed into the constructor when you instantiate a new UserTasksType object, which effectively gives your UserTasksType access to the entity manager.

If you aren't using the entity manager in your UserTasksType, there is no need to inject it in the constructor and you could get rid of the two lines above and the `__construct()` / `setUr()` methods in your UserTasksType.

A better example to help you understand DIC might be that you have a service that is written specifically to send emails (Swiftmail, for e.g.) and you need to inject it into another service so that service can send emails.

By adding

```
arguments: [ @mailer ]
```

to your service definition, your services constructor will expect your mailer service

```
__construct ($mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}
```

which will give it access to send emails

```
someFunction()
{
    //do something useful, then send an email using the swift mailer service
    $this->mailer->sendEmail();
}
```

Check out the latest Symfony docs for more of an explanation.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, But why I get that Catchable Fatal Error?

Comment: Because in your constructor of your UsersTasksType class, you're telling it to expect an entity manager: public function __construct(EntityManager  $ur ) and you're instantiating it with new UsersTasksType() -- ie, you're not giving it an entity manager.

Comment: Ok, So When I am using `NEW` to instantiate I have to pass `EntityManager` to my class, but when using `$this->container->get('the_service');` it will get automatically injected. Right?

Comment: No, you will always have to use new when you're instantiating a new instance of a class.  The difference is whether or not you have the entity manager (or any other service) defined in the constructor of the class you're instantiating.