# Symfony2 Using an Entity Manager within Twig extension

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm creating a menu system using the Tree Doctrine extenion and I want to create a Twig extension to display the menu based on the requested parent node e.g. `{% display_menu(side_menu) %}`. This function will be in the base twig template (i.e. the menu is on every page of the website).

As I'll be storing the Menu structure with Doctrine, I thought I'd need to access the MenuRepository within the Twig extension so the first problem I came across was getting an Entity Manager into it. When looking for a solution, a [few](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=35202&p=117613) [people](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony-devs/37T1LP4EOqY/N_VrFV7hwCMJ) have said that this is bad practice, which makes sense as a Twig extension is part of the View.

So although there is a solution (linked in similar questions) to my problem, my question is, is there a way I can accomplish it using *good* practice? Or is there a better way of doing it in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making entities aware of any services — including entity managers — is a bad practice. There's nothing wrong about injecting an EM into a Twig extension. Although, I'd rather inject a model manager to a Twig extension, so that the extension is not aware of the persistence layer — it's the job of the manager layer.

So, I'd have `MenuManager` that's aware of repositores/entity managers and inject it to an extension.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll use the accepted answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450465/fetching-data-through-a-custom-repository-in-a-twig-extension?rq=1) in this case.