# How can I check if a non-logged in user has a role?

Tags: php, symfony, roles

I have a situation where I need to check the roles for a user who isn't logged in.

I was originally simply querying the `users` table's `roles` field to see if the role in question was contained, but this does not take into account role heirarchy. For example, if a user has been granted `ROLE_ADMIN` they would also have `ROLE_USER`. However, you won't see `ROLE_USER` in the database, since in this case it's included in `ROLE_ADMIN`.

I'm a bit unfamiliar with the inner workings of Symfony2's security mechanism - I'd like to possibly "mock" a token for a user (based on their username) but I'm not sure how to, or if it's even possible. I've been digging around the Security component, but haven't found a solution yet.

Is it possible to check the roles of a user that is not logged in?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but try looking at `RoleHierarchyVoter` which is what the security system uses to resolve current roles. Last time I looked at it this class actually reads the security config for its own purposes and there wasn't a central location that you could query role hierarchy from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the list of roles users have, have a look at this code

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy;

//....
$roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchy($this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles'));
$userRoles = array(new Role('ROLE_ADMIN')); // Or $securityContext->getToken()->getRoles()
$reachableRoles = $roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles($userRoles);
```

**Notice:** Those methods are deprecated since Symfony 4.3

Comment: Is this code written in a controller or can I use it directly on my `User` class?? I ask for the container, which is not always accessible... I don't understand the container object yet.

Comment: Yes it is applicable for controller or any `ContainerAware` object. You can create a method in `User` class and pass the roles and parameter to use it. But I think `User` class is not right place for it. It would be better to create a service and place the method there. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124444/how-can-i-access-a-service-outside-of-a-controller-with-symfony2) question.