# Symfony 2 - Accessing Hierarchical Roles in a twig template

Tags: php, symfony, roles, twig

In my template, I need to know if a user has certain role to display things according to it. So far, I've implemented a little function in my user class:

```
  public function hasRole($role) {
    $roles = array();
    foreach ($this->getRoles() as $rol) {
      $roles[] = $rol->getRole();
    }
    return in_array($role, $roles);
  }
```

which tells me if this user has the role specified by the string passed as a parameter. This work and can be called from a twig template, but doesn't allow me to know anything about the roles hierarchy. Is there a way to access the role hierarchy from a controller? and directly from a twig template? I've looked through the official docs and didn't find anything about.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9542145/1218997) answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check the roles in twig templete by using below code,It explains that if the current user has the below role,then show something

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}

  //show things related to admin role

{%else if is_granted('ROLE_USER')%}
//show things related to user role
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps you.
Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One question: What if my user has the `ROLE_SUPERADMIN` which is hierarchically greater than `ROLE_ADMIN`? does `{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}` evaluate `true`?

Comment: Throoze@: if a user logged in with ROLE_SUPERADMIN ,he is hierarchically greater than ROLE_ADMIN(hope hierarchical order you specified in secutiy.yml),then it will evaluate true,because hierarchically he is a user with both ROLE_SUPERADMIN and ROLE_ADMIN so it becomes True

Comment: sorry for bothering you... which is the equivalent to `is_granted()` in a controller?

Comment: Throoze@: in controller you can check the users in role wise as below code  if(TRUE === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')){//superADMIN} else if(TRUE === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){//ADMIN}