# Symfony - How to pass a variable to an embedded form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm facing a problem with Symfony3 and forms.

I have a **Parent** form with an embedded **Child** form. From the controller, I can send data I can use in the **Parent** form with the $options array ($options['varA'], ...).

```
$form = $this->createForm(ParentEntityType::class, $objParent, array('varA'=>$varA, 'varB'=>$varB));
```

But what if I want to pass the varB variable (for example) to the embedded form ? What's the proper solution ?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272353/pass-value-in-options-array-to-embedded-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, in the first form:

```
$builder->add('name', MyFormType::class, [
            'data' => $options['varB']
]);
```

But better if you share your forms codes. The main key is to pass variables by $options['key'] in buildForm() method.

Comment: It's also possibly to use the 'entry_options' attribute, to pass any data to the embedded form. Like: `'entry_options' => [ 'varNameInEmbeddedForm' => $varB ];` That should be working since 2.8, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

this is a proper way in 2.7
in controller use this:

```
$itemform = $this->createForm(new SyllabusType(), $item, array('databranchid' => $branchid));
```

and in form use this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('studentclassid', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>'Schoolerp\Bundle\DBBundle\Entity\Studentclass',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $e) use ( $options ){
                return $e->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.isactive=1')
                    ->andWhere('u.branchid = ?1')
                    ->setParameter(1, $options['databranchid']);
            }
        ))
        ->add('sectionid', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>'Schoolerp\Bundle\DBBundle\Entity\Sections',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $e) use ( $options ){
                return $e->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.isactive=1')
                    ->andWhere('u.branchid = ?1')
                    ->setParameter(1, $options['databranchid']);
            }
        ));
```

```php
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Schoolerp\Bundle\DBBundle\Entity\Syllabus',
        'databranchid' => null
    ));
}
```

and if you use 3.0 replace input type into class type.

Answer (score 0):

> it's just simple pass values this way:

```
 $builder->add('userid', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>'DBBundle\Entity\AdminUser',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $e) use ( $options ){
                return $e->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.status=1')
                    ->andWhere('u.id = ?1')
                    ->setParameter(1, $options['users']);
            },
            'attr' => array('style'=>'display:none'),
            'label_attr' => array('style' =>'display:none')));
```