# Use a service when creating a twig filter (outside a controller)

Tags: php, service, symfony, twig

I have my class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension, where i have created my filters for twig. 
I want to use a service in the implementation of a new filter. Something like this:

```
$canView = $this->get('security_service')
                ->hasClassPermission(
                        'MyBundle:MyEntity',
                        $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(), 
                        array(MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW)
                 );
```

Into a controller this work fine, but outside it...

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer I gave on dependency injection outside a controller [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127711/697930).

Then check this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service) to see how to register your `TwigExtension` as a service.

Just a quick edit, sometimes, when you do `TwigExtension` as a service, you can't inject directly some service because it cause a `ScopeWideningException`. If you get this exception, then you can add `scope = request` to you service definition. If it still throws an exception, inject the whole dependency container and do `$this->container->get('service.id.here')` to retrieve the services you need.

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Matt